# Translating Mapping long/lat code from R (sp pkg) to Python

Tags: python, r, mapping, coordinates, r-sp

This is my first time asking question in Stack Overflow, I hope I am providing enough information.

Spyder 3.2.3
Python 3.6.2 64bits, Qt 5.6.2, PyQt5 5.6 on Windows 10

I have written code in R to identify and map clusters using Long/Lat

I am now tasked with translating it into Python language for which I am not even novice yet (can harldy spell python, lol.

Here is sample data:
Actual number of records = 2350 and other non-essential columns for my immediate question needs

```
x <- tmp1[,c(4)]
head(x,n=15)
```

-79.86286  -81.47581  -73.99576  -91.58647  -82.05398  -76.72366  -87.31574 -122.73485  -89.61309  -87.70185  -70.97230  -73.79628  -73.74651  -96.82385 -112.01015

```
y <- tmp1[,c(5)]
head(y,n=15)
```

40.43981 31.21329 40.80918 42.07720 26.77963 39.95549 41.51222 42.37320 39.84502 42.07626 42.37230 41.21192 40.70294 32.41051 41.52537

Here is the first step of the process and where I encounter my first error:
In Spyder I get this "colon" error

```
xy = r.SpatialPointsDataFrame(matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2), 
     r.data.frame(ID = r.seq(1:length(x))),
     proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
```

Error here: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
data.frame(ID=seq(1:length(x))),

One of many links I have perused for help
[Getting a Colon Syntax Error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849068/getting-a-colon-syntax-error-in-python)

IN R it looks like this:

```
xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2), data.frame(ID=seq(1:length(x))),
                         proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
```

I Tried with & w/o the :, with a , and no 1?

I have reviewed many links trying to get past this first step but have found no solution

I have tried to parse it out piece by piece and naturally get other errors as well.

```
r.data.frame(ID = r.seq(1:length(x)))
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
xy = r.SpatialPointsDataFrame(matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2), 
r.data.frame(ID = r.seq(1:length(x))),
proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
```

AttributeError: 'R' object has no attribute 'SpatialPointsDataFrame'''

https://rdrr.io/r/base/seq.html

```
xy = r.SpatialPointsDataFrame(matrix(c(x,y), ncol=2))
```

AttributeError: 'R' object has no attribute 'SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
proj4string=r.CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
proj4string=robjects.CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
proj4string=r.CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
```

AttributeError: module 'rpy2.robjects' has no attribute 'CRS

```
proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
```

NameError: name 'CRS' is not defined

I believe I have followed all the preparation steps to work with R in Python using rpy2:
Import rpy2 then Import R
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/robjects_rpackages.html
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.1.x/html/_modules/rpy2/robjects/packages.html

Using R inside python

```
import rpy2
print(rpy2.__version__)
```

3.3.3

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html
 Get necessary tools

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

from rpy2.robjects import DataFrame, Formula

import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr  

from rpy2.robjects import r   

utils = rpackages.importr('utils')

utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)  
base = importr('base')
```

[rpy2 - 'R' object has no attribute 'nls'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442703/rpy2-r-object-has-no-attribute-nls)
Alternative Only

```
base = importr('base', robject_translations={'with': '_with'})

base
```

rpy2.robjects.packages.Package as a

```
stats = importr('stats')
```

Alternative Only

```
stats = importr('stats', robject_translations={'format_perc': '_format_perc'})

stats
```

rpy2.robjects.packages.Package as a

```
packnames = ('ggplot2', 
'usmap','geosphere','sp','rdgal','ggmap','maps','mapdata','ggcorrplot','reshape2','dplyr'
         ,'magrittr''devtools','proj4')

from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))
```

Alternative Only: I have not used this yet

```
names_to_install = [x for x in packnames if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)]
if len(names_to_install) > 0:
utils.install_packages(StrVector(names_to_install))
```

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html

```
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/r_interface.html

```
pandas2ri.activate()
import rpy2.robjects as ro
```

I hope someone can provide me with some direction.

Thank you.

WHP

Comment: what is the `r` object in your python code?

Comment: There are two options, the first one is reading about `rpy2` and use R functions in python, or you can read about `pandas` and `geopandas` and rewrite your functions. I guess rpy2 is the fastest way. But whichever route you choose, take your time and try to follow a tutorial first and understand what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you Sergio, after several attempts I I have abandoned the rpy2 option and I am teaching myself python using this task. Reviewing pandas and geopandas documents. I expect to have new questions shortly. Please consider this question closed